# Single-subscriber event

Tags: c#

Currently, I use the following code to implement an event, in a class, that can have a maximum of one event handler registered to it:

```
private event EventHandler<EventArgs> e_Foo;

public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Foo {
    add {
        if (e_Foo != null && e_Foo.GetInvocationList().Any())
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Only one event handler may be registered at a time.");
        e_Foo += value;
    }
    remove {
        e_Foo -= value;
    }
}

private void OnFoo() {
    if (e_Foo != null)
        e_Foo(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

- Is there a better way?
- Is there any way I can wrap this up in a class so I don't have to copy and paste so much code?

Comment: What's  wrong with subscribing multiple event handlers?

Comment: @dtb, Only one subscriber makes sense here. Forgetting to unsubscribe causes conflicts so I want to enforce this.

Comment: I think you should solve this problem in a way, not by changing the usual way how events work. By the way, your code doesn't satisfy your requirement, since a delegate instance can have multiple invocation targets.

Comment: I have a device object that raises events depending on different packets it receives. This device is shared, in sequence, by a series of different subscribers. If one forgets to unsubscribe when it is finished with the device, its event handler will still execute, even though it should not.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the [Weak Event Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events are just a special way to expose delegate properties with special semantics: Instead of setting the value, you add and remove handlers.  If this behavior doesn't work for you, then trying to remove it from events is just creating unnecessary complication.  Instead, why not simply avoid adding the behavior you don't want in the first place by directly exposing the callback as a delegate property?

```
public Action<T1, T2> Foo {get; set;}

private void OnFoo(T1, T2) 
{
    var handler = Foo;
    if(handler != null) handler(T1, T2);
}
```

This way, when someone sets `OnFoo` it will use normal property semantics and replace the delegate instance rather than throwing it on the pile.  It doesn't get rid of multicast, but it doesn't sound to me like that's really your problem anyway.

Comment: Events just seemed like the *normal* way of handling callbacks, so I just never thought of this. This is what I'm using now and it definitely simplifies things. I still with they had a non-multicast delegate type though.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I used to worry about that, too, but I've made my peace with it and have come around to thinking that caring about it is something of a code smell.  Ideally, if your object's properly encapsulated then you shouldn't have any reason to care whether its users are composing delegates or not. It's just syntactic sugar for something you can't prevent, anyway. Consider `myObject.Callback = () => { x.Foo(); y.Bar(); }`

Answer (score 2):

This should really be a comment, but I need to write code:

```
private void OnFoo() {
    if (e_Foo != null)
        e_Foo(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

introduces a potential race condition because the invocation list might change between the check and the actual invocation. You might end up invoking null. It should be:

```
private void OnFoo() {
    var fuFoo = e_Foo;
    if (fuFoo != null)
        fuFoo(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

***NOTE: It's 2020 and since C# 6, we've had the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/csharp-the-new-and-improved-csharp-6-0#null-conditional-operator).***

This can be used to express the previous code in a much simpler way:

```
private void OnFoo() {
    e_Foo?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

I suppose a less error-prone way is a better way. I win!

Comment: Thank you. I have seen the local variable copy before invocation, but forgot to implement that here. Of course, the whole single-subscriber issue remains.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to reduce the code a lot, but you could put the check in a method that does the work for you, or returns the handler, like so:

```
public EventHandler<T> HookUp<T>(EventHandler<T> myEvent, EventHandler<T> myMethod)
    where T : EventArgs
{
    if (myEvent != null && myEvent.GetInvocationList().Any())
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Only one event handler may be registered at a time.");
    return myMethod;
}

private event EventHandler<EventArgs> e_Foo;

public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Foo
{
    add { e_Foo += HookUp(e_Foo, value); }
    remove { e_Foo -= value; }
}
```

You could implement an interface that has all that logic in some extension methods, or inherit an abstract class. But then, you'd have to have multiple interfaces for each number of events you want (`ISingleSubscriberOne`, `ISingleSubscriberTwo`, `ISingleSubscriberThree`, and so on).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible in your scenario, but I would proably assign the event code to an Action variable and link the event to that Action. Then the users would only be able to change the Action and never really alter the registered events on my event. The event would simply link to the action so that you can change the action, but you can never have 2 at the same time.

Just a thought. Haven't had coffee yet, so this may not be appropriate at all...